# How to connect to server using TCP

Tags: java, android, tcp

I would like to implement an easy server client application with Android Studio to communicate with my computer.

My phone is my server and my computer is my client. So I have to open a new ServerSocket with my phone:

```
ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(port);
Socket clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();
```

And on my Computer I need a Client Socket:

```
Socket echoSocket = new Socket(addr, port);
```

I'm getting a java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused error on my computer.

How do I find out which InetAddr I have to use? I know, that Android Studio is using 10.0.2.2, but this doesn't work. I've also tried to use 127.0.0.1 and the IPv4 Address of the android emulator, which is shown in the settings.

I've also checked if I can see the waiting port with cmd.exe

```
netstat -a
```

but there is no service waiting/listening on my port. Is Android able to 'host' a server via TCP? If so, which local address do I have to use?

Many thanks for help!

Comment: As it is common for modern gateways to also feature a DHCP-Service we cannot tell you which IP your phone is currently haveing. You have to look it up yourself. Luckily it should found somewhere under the device settings or information. What I can say is that it should be able to use your phone as a Server (It is very rare and I would strongly advise to go the other way around: Let your PC be the server and your phone the client, as it is a far more real world example).

Comment: Android will let apps be the server; just make sure you choose a high port number (not a [well-known port](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_TCP_and_UDP_port_numbers#Well-known_ports)). You won't see your emulator's server on Window's `netstat`, though; you need to do an [adb shell netstat](http://adbshell.com/commands/adb-shell-netstat).

Comment: Many thanks for your help. My PC is now my server and it works! :)